# Null value when submitting form

Tags: jsp

I have a three radio button in my JSP page. I am displaying multi select box based on radio button selected.
But while submitting form, i am getting null value from two select box. Other select box is working fine.

Can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show').hide();
$("input[name$='application']").click(function() {
var test = $(this).val();
$("div.show").hide();
$('#showemma').hide();
$('#showdmfota').hide();
$('#showuep').hide();
$("#show" + test).show();
   });
});
</script>
<title>Add Config Changes</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Server env = new Server();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = env.getServer();
    Properties property = new Properties();
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    property.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("error.properties"));
%>
<h3> Add Configuration Change</h3> <br><br>
<form action="_config" method="post">
<table align="center" id ="login">
    <tr>
        <td>Application</td>
            <td>
            <div class="radio" style="font-size:12px;">
                <label><input type="radio" name="application" id="fota" value="dmfota"> DMFOTA</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="application" id="uep" value="uep"> UEP</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="application" id="emma" value="emma"> EMMA</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        <td id="error"><p id ="applicationError"><%=property.getProperty("applicationError") %></p></td>
    </tr>           

    <% for (String serverNamekey : map.keySet()){%>
    <tr id="show<%= serverNamekey %>" class="show" style='display:none'>

        <td>Server</td>
            <td>
            <% List<String> servers = map.get(serverNamekey); %>
                <select name="server" id="server" multiple="multiple" style="width:150px; height: 150px;">
                    <%for (String serverName : servers){  %>
                        <option value="<%=serverName%>"><%=serverName%></option>
                    <%} %>
                </select> 
            </td> 
            <td id="error"><p id ="serverError"><%=property.getProperty("serverError") %></p></td>
    </tr>
            <%} %>
    <tr>
        <td colspan =2><input type="submit" value="Add Change Log"   id="configSubmit" class="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>

</table>
</form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Your input name is always `name="server"` for all inputs, so for your id. You should provide unique for both.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: I have changed id and name to unqiue. It didnt worked.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to see the changes?

Comment: Please [avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1037210) this hateful scriptlets which is **highly** discouraged for over a decade.

Comment: how you are getting value of select in your java class?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya  Map<String, List<String>> map = env.getServer(); I have a map which has list of server name as a key and list of servers as a string as a value.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie   Thank you. I have changed name and now its working fine.

Comment: @Kalpesh Excellent, note : I've rolled back your question and added the answer for the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your `name` attribute must be unique on all inputs, ortherwise, only one value will be take into account by the server. Moreover, `id` must also be unique.

I recommand to use the `serverNameKey` as unique `name` and `id` :

```
<select id="select-<%= serverNamekey %>" name="<%= serverNamekey %>" ...
```

Note that you need the same `name` attribute for all `input type="radio"`, so that part is okay.

---

Not related to the problem, I also recommand to not use scriplets, you should read about JSTL. If it is a new project, I recommand usage of JSF which took over on JSP (that is deprecated).

Comment: I will look  in to your suggestion. Thanks a lot !!